# how to resize an html canvas only on the screen?

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on an artistic project with html5 using canvas :

i need to draw on canvas 2200px/1600px (width/height) but i must to show it on my web site in smaller window (600px/400px) but after the modification from the client i need to convert this canvas to an image with the original width and height (2200 px/1600).

```
 <canvas id="iBack"   style="width:<?= $backgroundWidth ?>px;  height:<?= $backgroundHeigth ?>px; z-index: 0;  border: 1px dotted red; "></canvas>
```

Comment: So what your problem is?

Comment: Please share some of the code you tried with. You will run into a couple of challenges here. 1) The scale is pretty rough so for the image to look any good you need to downscale in steps (not so important if you're only using vectors). 2) Input coordinates will have to be scaled as well (the other way). Being 1:1 in scaled state means your resulting points will be quantized to the scale factor which may not look so good if you draw for example lines - in fact, for vectors there is no point doing the canvas scaling at all as you simply scale the points when they need to be scaled (zoom/final).

Answer (score 0):

You could use css if you scale proportionally to avoid distortion.

```
var scale=2200/600;
canvas.style.width*=scale;
canvas.style.height*=scale;
```

This might leave your image+text looking too pixelated after scaling.

If its too pixelated for your taste, you can redraw the larger original image with scaled text.

Here's code and a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dZ4D6/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var scale=1.0;
    var fontsize=36;
    var fontface="verdana";
    var fullImageWidth,fullImageHeight;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
       redraw(img,"Hello",20,35,1.25); 
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";

    function redraw(img,text,textX,textY,scale){

        canvas.width=img.width*scale;
        canvas.height=img.height*scale;

        // draw the scaled image
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,img.width*scale,img.height*scale);

        ctx.font=(fontsize*scale)+"px "+fontface;

        // draw the scaled text
        ctx.fillText(text,textX*scale,textY*scale);

    }

    $("#redraw").click(function(){
        if(scale==1.00){
            scale=0.50;
        }else{
            scale=1.00;
        }
        redraw(img,"Hello",20,35,scale); 
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="redraw">Redraw</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```